# How to create an svg sprite which supports fragment identifiers?

Tags: svg, fragment, sprite, amp-html

There are multiple svg icons. To reduce the requests on the page an svg sprite was created to not have a request for every icon. The svg sprite gets lazyloaded via javascript and SVGs of that sprite are referenced by:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><use xlink:href="<id_from_sprite>"></use></svg>
```

This works fine for the desktop and mobile website. But it's not working for AMP (javascript restrictions). During my research I came across this article: https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

Icons from svg sprites could then be referenced like this:

```
<img src="svg_sprite.svg#icon_from_the_sprite" alt="" />
```

The problem is that the original icons from the sprite have similiar viewBoxes, all start at x-coordinate 0 and y coordinate 0 and laying over each other in the automatically created sprite. For the fragment identifier to work they would need to be aligned one over the other. I have no Adobe Illustrator to redraw them and I'm not aware of any automated tool that changes the viewBoxes AND the coordninates of the Icons automatically. Did anyone encounter the same problem and could provide some tips or a solution for that? Is there a tool that creates from random SVGs a sprite where the icons are aligned one under the other with adjusted viewBoxes and added `<view>` attributes and icon not within a `<def>` tag?

Comment: Why can't you just use the way the article describes, for icons that _are_ stacked on top of each other? https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/#aa-i-just-wanna-stack-the-icons-on-top-of-each-other

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Well, to be honest I think I ruled that one out because inline CSS is involved which is usually restricted in AMP. But since it's an external request it might doesn't matter and validate anyway. I'll give it a try!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-sprite

Answer (score -1):

It helped me to put the styles specifically in the html style

before

```
<svg>
<defs>
<style>
 .test {
   fill: #fff;
 }
</style>
</defs>
<circle class="test"> ...
```

after

```
<svg>
<circle style="fill: #fff"> ...
```